# How to test a socket.io endpoint with cookie based authentication?

Tags: cookies, websocket, socket.io, mocha.js, integration-testing

I would like to perform integration tests on my socket.io namespaces, however all requests are piped through a middleware that checks for a valid session using the express-session module. What I am looking for is a way to either attach a cookie to the socket.io client before performing the request or if there is another way to perform tests would also like to hear about it.

Here is some server side code

```
const session = require('express-session')({
....
})
const Server = require('socket.io');

const io = new Server();

io.use(function(socket,next){
   session(socket.request, {}, next);
});

io.on('connection',...);
```

now on the client

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const cli1 = new io(); //Here is where I need to pass my connect.sid cookie.
```

I have skimmed the actual socket.io-client source and there doesn't seem to be anything, so if there are any alternatives I would love to hear about them.

Comment: not sure but do you need [this](https://gist.github.com/jfromaniello/4087861)